# Listening to recorded adhan and multitasking

Tags: adhan

Can we play recordings of adhan on mobile phones while doing activities like studying, working or sleeping?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 0):

A muslim does what benefits him in the hereafter. Is there any benefit in listening to adhan while studying, working and sleeping? Benefit is defined as a reward from Allah for a specific action. Adhan is a call for prayer. Hence there is no benefit in listening to Adhan during the activities you mentioned. And moreover there is no evidence from the companions of Muhammed(ﷺ) that they used to listen to adhan during the above mentioned activities.

Comment: Is there any restriction to doing it? Will I be a sinner if I play it and dont pay much attention?

Comment: There is no restriction and there is no sin involved here.